# how to add new field in post table in Pyrocms with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pyrocms

I want to add a new field in post table in Pyrocms with laravel.
I just add a new field in the table but I cannot send data in the field.

Comment: Try to refresh your database with migration !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to bind your own `PostTableBuilder` to the core one and just modify the `$columns` attribute.

Keep an eye on https://pyrocms.com/help/developer-tools/extending-pyrocms for more help on the subject.

Comment: thanks so much for your quite impressive PyroCMS. I'm excited about what I might be able to do with it (just getting started now and might be able to contribute something cool). I'm wondering if you can point me to anything that might help me past where I'm stumbling here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50518784/470749 Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

Please add fields in the `$fillable` variable of your model.

Have a look here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent under `Mass Assignment`.