# How to override a model class in PyroCMS (Laravel, PHP)?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pyrocms

I installed **PyroCMS** and am extending it to make it into a Learning Management System (LMS) where only logged-in users can view the pages, and the pages also only begin to be viewable a variable number of days after a user enrolls in the course.

(I.e., Module 1's Lesson 1 may unlock and be visible immediately, but Lesson 2 could be configured to be hidden until 1 day later, and Lesson 3 might become visible X days later, etc.)

How I achieved this was by writing a Laravel package with this migration:

```
Schema::table('pages_pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('drip_delay')->nullable()->after('str_id');
});
```

I then created a `DrippablePagesServiceProvider` class with this in the `boot()` function:

```
$this->app->bind('Anomaly\PagesModule\Http\Controller\PagesController', 'me\DrippablePages\PagesController'); //https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#binding
```

I designed my custom `PagesController` to show a special view whenever the logged-in user is trying to access a page too early. This functionality is all working totally fine.

**But instead of editing the `drip_delay` field directly in the database like I've been doing, I'd prefer to be able to edit right alongside the other fields at the /admin/pages/edit/4 URL.**

I'm pretty sure I need to override various parts of [PagesModule](https://pyrocms.com/documentation/pages-module/2.3/), such as PageEntryFormSections ([doc](https://pyrocms.com/help/addon-development/modules/implementing-custom-fields)). And I think I have that working.

But when stepping through with Xdebug, I see that the PageModel that gets looked up at [this line](https://github.com/anomalylabs/pages-module/blob/v2.3.0/src/Http/Controller/Admin/PagesController.php#L67) (via dependency injection?†) in `edit()` within `Http\Controller\Admin\PagesController` still doesn't show my new `drip_delay` field.

**How can I override PageModel or do whatever I need to do so that it shows the `drip_delay` field in this Admin panel view?**

† Laravel docs about [container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#automatic-injection) and [controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers) imply this.

Comment: Short answer is that you can override any of these classes by binding your own to them. However for form sections, injecting more forms into the multiple form builder for pages, and other things you can use callbacks on the form builders. Sounds like this package is already done and you want to tack it onto Pyro - which you can totally do. Perhaps our forum / slack though would be a better platform as you'll need more guidance than "an answer" can provide.

http://pyrocms.com/slack
http://pyrocms.com/forum

Comment: I have a few examples of overriding models of streams addons: there are all bindings https://github.com/Piterden/ppp/blob/master/src/PppModuleServiceProvider.php#L51-L65 , there is PageModel https://github.com/Piterden/ppp/blob/master/src/Page/PageModel.php#L15 , and next is PostModel https://github.com/Piterden/ppp/blob/master/src/Post/PostModel.php#L12

Answer (score 2):

To override a model first you need a new one which extends a model you want to override:

```
<?php namespace Ryan\ExtenderModule\Post;

class PostModel extends \Anomaly\PostsModule\Post\PostModel
{

}
```

Then inside the `ServiceProvider` you need to bind it reversed:

```
<?php namespace Ryan\ExtenderModule;

use Anomaly\PostsModule\Post\PostModel;
use Anomaly\Streams\Platform\Addon\AddonServiceProvider;

class ExtenderModuleServiceProvider extends AddonServiceProvider
{
    protected $bindings = [
        PostModel::class => \Ryan\ExtenderModule\Post\PostModel::class,
    ];
}
```

That's all. Good luck ))

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and your examples from your comment above, too. I was very excited to see this and try it out. So I moved my code from a package to an addon module. The good news is that the functionality that I had working before still works (`class PagesController extends \Anomaly\PagesModule\Http\Controller\PagesController`). (It prevents people from seeing certain pages too soon.) The bad news is that me visiting /admin/pages/edit/4 produces this error: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Anomaly\PagesModule\Page\PageRepository::__construct() must be an instance of ...`

Comment: `... Anomaly\PagesModule\Page\PageModel, instance of Ss\SuperpagesModule\Page\PageModel given` even though I have these bindings: `[
        \Anomaly\PagesModule\Http\Controller\PagesController::class => \Ss\SuperpagesModule\Http\Controller\PagesController::class,
        \Anomaly\PagesModule\Page\Form\PageEntryFormSections::class => \Ss\SuperpagesModule\Page\PageEntryFormSections::class,
        \Anomaly\PagesModule\Page\PageModel::class => \Ss\SuperpagesModule\Page\PageModel::class,
        ...`

Comment: `...\Anomaly\Streams\Platform\Model\Pages\PagesPagesEntryModel::class => \Ss\SuperpagesModule\PagesPagesEntryModel::class,        
    ]`. Any ideas? I appreciate your help so much.

Comment: Don't extend a controller. Try to do it with an other way. Also, do you have a repository with your addon code? Let me check it out, please. You can create one at the GitLab

Comment: Another idea is to extend `Anomaly\PagesModule\Page\PageRepository` too

Comment: Thank you for the offer of looking at my code. Unfortunately I'm still confused about Streams (https://pyrocms.com/documentation/streams-platform/1.4/addons/the-basics)(don't yet see how it's better than Laravel), and I could never figure out how to do the equivalent of the migration shown in my question, so I couldn't figure out how to share a working addon repo for you.

Comment: At this point, I've spent too much time trying to learn how to do something that I thought would be basic: add 1 simple field within PyroCMS (i.e. adding my `string('drip_delay')->nullable()` to extend the existing PageModel and PagesModule), so I'm going to take a break from Pyro for now and work on other projects. I appreciated your interest in helping me, though! :-)

Comment: https://github.com/Piterden/ppp/blob/master/migrations/2017_04_21_091017_qooco.module.ppp__add_fields.php
https://github.com/Piterden/ppp/blob/master/migrations/2017_04_26_141027_qooco.module.ppp__add_page_fields.php

Here are examples of extending some streams models.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look.